# how to browse all messages from 2 different MQQueue in the same function?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

My purpose is to list down the correlation ids of the messages in a set of MQ Queues in my Java application.

This is the code snippet

```
public void populateCorrelationIds() throws MQException{
    int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQConstants.MQOO_INQUIRE | MQConstants.MQOO_BROWSE;
    String qNames[0] = BAY10.CISCHGX.DFDA;
    String qNames[1] = BAYSF11.MSFCHGX.DFDA;
    MQMessage messageGet = new MQMessage();
    for(String q : qNames){
        MQQueue dfdaQ  = qMgr.accessQueue(q, openOptions);
        MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
        gmo.options = MQConstants.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST| MQConstants.MQGMO_WAIT;
        gmo.waitInterval = 4000;
        int j = dfdaQ.getCurrentDepth();
        for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            dfdaQ.get(messageGet,gmo);  //Error generated here when getting message for qNames[1]
            byte[] correlId= messageGet.correlationId;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the error I am getting --

```
MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2033'. com.ibm.mq.MQException: 
MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2033'. at    
com.ibm.mq.MQDestination.getInt(MQDestination.java:655) at 
com.ibm.mq.MQDestination.get(MQDestination.java:459) at 
Utility.populateCorrelationIds(Utility.java:152) at 
Utility.main(Utility.java:64) MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2033'.
```

This is the error I get when I run the code. Please note the error occurs when I get the message from the queue for the next queue. I am successfully able to browse all messages for the first queue. But as soon as I browse the first message in second queue I get the above error. Can anyone help in resolving this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple points to note here:

The first one is because you are initializing `MQMessage` object outside the first `for` loop. It has to be inside the second `for` loop because MQ fills that object with `MessageId`, `CorrelationId`, message body among others when `MQQueue.get` call returns. If you make `get` call again with same `MQMessage` object instance, you are actually attempting to get a message with MessageId of the previously retrieved message. This call with fail with 2033 reason code.

There are few other points about your code.

1) You have to do a `new MQGetMessageOptions()` inside the second `for` loop.

2) You are using BROWSE_FIRST option. This will browse the fist message only. To browse all message, you have to do a `get` with `BROWSE_NEXT` option. When you open a queue, the browse cursor is positioned logically just before the first message on the queue. This means that if you make your `get` call immediately after your `accessQueue` call, you can use the `MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT` option to browse the first message; you do not have to use the `MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST` option

3) If the queue is opened for `browse` only, then there is no need for specifying `MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQConstants.MQOO_INQUIRE` open options.

4) The getCurrentDepth() method returns the queue depth when the call was made. It is possible that while your application is browsing, some other application might get messages from the same queue. In that case, the current queue depth will change but your application will not be notified of the change. So instead of using `dfdaQ.getCurrentDepth()`, you can simply do get with `MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT` option in a `while` loop. The get call will return with 2033 reason code when there are no messages to browse. You can check for this reason code and exit out the while loop.

Comment: THanks, that was helpful. If I do not want to include the messages which have been in the queue for more than 30 seconds what function can I use?

Comment: Do a compare of the PutDate And PutTime with the time now modified by 30 seconds. There is no MQ API function for this comparison. The MQ API simply gives you access to the two fields you need in the MQMD.